# Stanford NER Tagger in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to import the Stanford Named Entity Recognizer in Python. This is already built in the NLTK package. However, my code below is not working:

```
 from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: cannot import name NERTagger
```

What could be the cause? In all articles I read it works by default. Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899656/stanford-ner-in-nltk-not-tagging-multiple-sentences-correctly-python and https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That class has been [renamed to `StanfordNERTagger` in version `3.0.3`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/ChangeLog#L54) (commit [`190673c7`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/190673c7a6c48620d37f5cd58e5e91851f6edbaf)).

So for `nltk >= 3.0.3` you need to use this import instead:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
```

*(You could also do `from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger`, but since they now also provide a convenience import in the `nltk.tag` module, that's probably what they want use to use, that import location should be less prone to future changes like this.)*

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the answer! :-)
I have a follow-up question to this: my code for NER seems to crash because of a Java issue:

from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', 'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar', encoding='utf-8')
st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())

It gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError. raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))

Comment: The rest of the error says this:

OSError: Java command failed : [u'/usr/bin/java', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier', '-loadClassifier', 'stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', '-textFile', '/var/folders/71/7xpdk_vs5gd9f_904kfqz4rh0000gn/T/tmpWS1NTV', '-outputFormat', 'slashTags', '-tokenizerFactory', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer', '-tokenizerOptions', '"tokenizeNLs=false"', '-encoding', 'utf-8']

Any idea why this happens? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really help you with that second error - I'm not really that familiar with NLTK (the import error I could pinpoint with just general Python knowledge and reading the history of the source code). I would suggest to create a new question for this issue.