# NLTK - Where is the organization names list stored in source file

Tags: java, python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

When i open the file i see different files which are full of java functions. But how nltk compare tokenized words with its database to check if the word is ogranization name or not ? Where is that organization name list ?

Sorry for bad english.

http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html

Comment: See NER section of https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899656/stanford-ner-in-nltk-not-tagging-multiple-sentences-correctly-python